# How to exclude transitive dependency for a react application

Tags: reactjs

My react application was created five years back. I am trying to fix the vulnerabilities in it but found a dependent library that was ten years old. Changing it to the latest is causing the application to fail due to a lot of other dependency incompatibilities.

I have overrides in my package.json.

How do I exclude only a specific transitive dependency in the react application?